# How to use the same math and text font as in this book?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

What is the math font used in *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* written by Brezis ([link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-0-387-70914-7.pdf)).
How can I use it in my own LaTeX document?

---

Edited (2022.10.16)

This question has been asked four months ago. Thanks to M. Logic, I know the math font used in this book is mtpro2 and now I want to know what kind of Times font is used in the book?

Comment: Looks like some Times version, but maybe only people at Springer knows. You could try `newtx` and see if it gives you what you want.

Comment: To generate the script `L` letter, you'll need to run `\usepackage[scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}` in the preamble and type `\mathscr{L}` (in math mode, obviously).

Comment: For the Times Roman math font, my guess is that the book used the [MathTime II Professional](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package.

Comment: @Mico You are right, and see also my post for more details.

Comment: @M.Logic - Glad we agree. :-) The decisive clues as to which main math font package might be in play were in the shapes of `\varphi`, `\psi`, and `\omega`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2022-10-18**

As what I said in the following, `newtxtext` is a free choice to the text font. From the latex templates provided by Springer, the text font is indeed `newtxtext`. See the page 1 in [*Manuscript Guidelines for English Books*](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/990/data/v24) for the download link. Note that the math(equation) font is `newtxmath` in the template while not `mtpro2`.

So the author of the book you provide possibly use `newtxtext` as the text font and `mtpro2` as the math(equation) font.

---

**2022-05-30**

The math fonts should be from the `mtpro2` package for which there is [a simplified version](https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) on CTAN while isn't in your TeX system, and you could also buy the complete version from [the link](https://pctex.com/mtpro2.html). Since the `mtpro2` package provides no text fonts, you should pick some text fonts to match with `mtpro2`, for which one free choice is the `newtxtext` package as shown in the following codes and output.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}

%%%fonts setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%text fonts setting-----------------------------------
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{newtxtext}%
%math fonts setting-------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}%use some basic math environments
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}%use \mathcal, \mathfrak, \mathbb, \mathscr 
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{hyperref}%use \eqref

\begin{document}
The following example comes from page 371 in the book you provided.
\begin{enumerate}
\item[3.] Note that
\[
\langle f,y\rangle\leq\lVert f\rVert\leq\lVert y\rVert\leq \frac{1}{2}\leq\lVert f\rVert^2+\frac{1}{2}\leq\lVert y\rVert^2.
\]
Conversely, assume that $f $satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\lVert y\rVert^2-\frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2\geq \langle f,y-x\rangle \forall y\in E.\tag{S1}\label{eq01}
\end{equation}
First choose $y = \lambda x$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ in \eqref{eq01}; by varying $\lambda$ one sees that $\langle f,x\rangle=\lVert x\rVert^2$. Next choose $y$ in \eqref{eq01} such that  $\lVert y\rVert=\delta\geq 0$; it follows that
\[
\langle f,y\rangle\leq \frac{1}{2}\delta^2+\frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2.
\]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another free choice given by the author of the `mtpro2` package is Adobe Times (`ptm`).

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

Both of them look very well if you ask for no more. While in fact, neither `newtxtext` nor `ptm` match completely with `mtpro2` in letter shapes, for example the italic z as shown in the following output.

[image]

The font series which the author of the `mtpro2` package recommends most and I find matchs best with `mtpro2` is the [Times New Roman Pro](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/times-new-roman-font-monotype-imaging) series produced by Monotype, which is also not free, and *has been in my hand*. If you want to buy them, then it's enough to buy four shapes: regular, italic, semibold, semibold italic. The following is a way to invoke both them and simplified `mtpro2`. The author of the `mtpro2` package also recommends Adobe Times, Times Ten and similar typefaces, such as Baskerville or Concorde to be the text fonts.

```
%%%fonts setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%text fonts setting-----------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont ={Times NR MT Pro Italic},
BoldFont ={Times NR MT Pro SemiBold},
BoldItalicFont ={Times NR MT Pro SemiBold It}]
{Times NR MT Pro}
%math fonts setting-------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}%use some basic math environments
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}%use \mathcal, \mathfrak, \mathbb, \mathscr 
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And if you also buy the complete `mtpro2` *which has been also in my hand*, then use the following codes.

```
%%%fonts setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%text fonts setting-----------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont ={Times NR MT Pro Italic},
BoldFont ={Times NR MT Pro SemiBold},
BoldItalicFont ={Times NR MT Pro SemiBold It}]{Times NR MT Pro}
%the full names may be different with different versions
%math fonts setting-------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}%use some basic math environments
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}%use \mathcal, \mathfrak, \mathbb, \mathscr 
\usepackage{mtpro2}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

You could also use `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak`, `\mathbb` and `\mathscr` in the `mtpro2` package by adding some options and deleting `\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}`.

Note: In my opinion, **using Times New Roman Pro as text fonts and fonts from `mtpro2` as math fonts is the best program so far as now to use Times in LaTeX**.

By the way, as you see, such Times fonts have a larger line weight than Computer Modern fonts, and match well with the screen in a not so high resolution. But if you read such Times texts on the screen in a high resolution, for example, the Macbook Pro Reinta screen, then some visual pressure would come out. So it's necessary to creat some Times fonts with a smaller line weight or with the similar line weight to Computer Modern fonts, which are not existed right now. And I have been designing such a Times series off and on for a long time.

Hope these useful for you.

Comment: +1. To make the screenshot approximate the book even more, you could employ the `svmono` document class as follows: `\documentclass[envcountchap]{svmono}`. To get a "swashy"-looking lowercase `z` letter in math mode when using the `mtpro2` package, it suffices to load the package with the option `zswash`.

Comment: @Mico In my opinion, the italic z produced by `zwash` is ugly ....

Comment: Why the `mtp2lite` package not in my texlive2022?

Comment: @Stephen Use XeLaTeX to compile the file?

Comment: Both `xelatex` and `pdflatex` issue an error.

Comment: @M.Logic And There is some bug in the `newtxtext` package.

Comment: @Stephen The error says what?

Comment: @M.Logic ! Font \MTEXA@=mt2exa at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed fo
nt not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \font 
l.130 \font
           \MTXL@=mt2xl at \the\dimen@
?

Comment: @Stephen You could ask a new question and post your codes.

Comment: ok. I write a new post.

Comment: @M.Logic By the way, did you know what is the text font used in this book?

Comment: @Stephen As what I said in the post, `newtxtext` is a free choice to the text font. And from the latex templates provided by Springer, the text font is indeed `newtxtext`. See the page 1 in [*Manuscript Guidelines for English Books*](https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/990/data/v24) for the download link. Note that the equation font is also `newtxmath` in default in the template not `mtpro2`.

Comment: The z with the swash tail is traditional in text, but it is inappropriate in math, where it can cause problems with subscripts.  Math publishers have for years made the substitution of z with a "straight" bottom.