# Error when using mtpro2 package

Tags: compilation-error, mtpro

Here is the code copied from my last [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646072/how-to-use-the-same-math-font-as-in-this-book) given by M. Logic.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{book}

%%%fonts setting%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%text fonts setting-----------------------------------
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{newtxtext}%
%math fonts setting-------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}%use some basic math environments
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}%use \mathcal, \mathfrak, \mathbb, \mathscr 
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{hyperref}%use \eqref

\begin{document}
The following example comes from page 371 in the book you provided.
\begin{enumerate}
\item[3.] Note that
\[
\langle f,y\rangle\leq\lVert f\rVert\leq\lVert y\rVert\leq \frac{1}{2}\leq\lVert f\rVert^2+\frac{1}{2}\leq\lVert y\rVert^2.
\]
Conversely, assume that $f $satisfies
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{2}\lVert y\rVert^2-\frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2\geq \langle f,y-x\rangle \forall y\in E.\tag{S1}\label{eq01}
\end{equation}
First choose $y = \lambda x$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ in \eqref{eq01}; by varying $\lambda$ one sees that $\langle f,x\rangle=\lVert x\rVert^2$. Next choose $y$ in \eqref{eq01} such that  $\lVert y\rVert=\delta\geq 0$; it follows that
\[
\langle f,y\rangle\leq \frac{1}{2}\delta^2+\frac{1}{2}\lVert x\rVert^2.
\]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'm using mac operating system and I have installed texlive 2022. After compiling the code by `xelatex`, the .log file is as follows:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.5.31)  31 MAY 2022 17:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test1
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-05-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo
File: leqno.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2b Standard LaTeX option (left equation numbers)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@chapter=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Changing ? sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 78.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
Package: newtxtext 2022/02/28 v1.71(Michael Sharpe) latex and unicode latex sup
port for TeXGyreTermesX

`newtxtext' v1.71, 2022/02/28 Text macros taking advantage of TeXGyre Termes an
d its extensions (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count190
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count191
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count192
\decimalpart=\count193
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting ntxLF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting ntxTLF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting ntxOsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Setting ntxTOsF sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 21.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
\ntx@tmpcnta=\count194
\ntx@cnt=\count195

ntx@otftexttrue
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-05-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count198
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count199
))
Package: xparse 2022-05-30 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count276
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen140
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen141

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 479.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \liningnums on input line 483.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty
Package: realscripts 2016/02/13 v0.3d Access OpenType subscripts and superscrip
ts
\subsupersep=\dimen142
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen143
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen144
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count277
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count278
\leftroot@=\count279
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count280
\DOTSCASE@=\count281
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen145
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count282
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count283
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count284
\dspbrk@lvl=\count285
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count286
\column@=\count287
\maxfields@=\count288
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen146
\alignsep@=\dimen147
\tagshift@=\dimen148
\tagwidth@=\dimen149
\totwidth@=\dimen150
\lineht@=\dimen151
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup6
)
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/mtpro2.sty
Package: mtpro2 2009/4/27 v2.3 MathTimePro II - added arc accents MathTimePro I
I - fixed rbrace problem with straightbraces and morphedbraces options MathTime
Pro II - fix bug with z = \backslash widetilde{\backslash sum_{x }}MathTimePro 
II v2 font support (PCTeX/WaS)MathTimePro II v2.1a Allowed alternate form of I 
in Math Script Fonts (MS)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 110.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 110.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)
```

and the VScode terminal reads

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-05-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
`newtxtext' v1.71, 2022/02/28 Text macros taking advantage of TeXGyre Termes an
d its extensions (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
ntx@otftexttrue
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/mtpro2.sty
kpathsea: Running mktextfm mt2exa
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mt2exa
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf mt2exa
! I can't find file `mt2exa'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mt2exa
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mt2exa
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: mt2exa.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mt2exa' failed to make mt2exa.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \MTEXA@=mt2exa at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed fo
nt not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \font 
l.130 \font
           \MTXL@=mt2xl at \the\dimen@
?
```

Comment: Did you also install the font? `kpathsea: Running mktextfm mt2exa` indicates that the font is not found

Comment: @daleif After downloading the .zip file from [ctan](https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite.zip), there are six directories in `texmf`, i.e.,  `doc`, `dvips`, `fonts`, `source`, `tex` and `tpm`. How should I place them in my local tex tree?

Comment: `mtpro2` is not a free font, also it is mostly designed for `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF` and `PDFLaTeX`

Comment: @Stephen For installation, you may see [here](https://pctex.com/kb/63.html).